# How to Set an alarm or a notification in background as a service and make it run even when the app is closed

Tags: android, service

I want to set(without displaying) an Alarm or a notification as a service or activity (in the background) at user specified hour, minute and with some text to display. thank you in advance

I got the code to set alarm and display it in the foreground. this code was written in the onCreate method:

```
if ((time2) < (times) && times < (time21)) {
   if(alarm1.isChecked()) {
       nextalarm1.setText(headers[i + 1]);
       Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
       intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, h1);
       intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, m1);
       intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, token[i+1]);
       startActivity(intent);
     }
 }
```

I want that the alarm should be set but not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The **JobScheduler** class allows you to set the conditions, or parameters, for when to run your task. Given these conditions, JobScheduler calculates the best time to schedule the execution of the job. For example, job parameters can include the persistence of the job across reboots, whether the device is plugged in, or whether the device is idle, or in a certain interval.

The services run in the background as you set condition.
REF: [JobScheduler](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-job-scheduler/index.html?index=..%2F..android-training#0)

In the JobService, OnStartJob you can trigger a notification. Here is the reference
REF: [Notification](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-notifications/index.html?index=..%2F..android-training#0)

Comment: can i set alarm as a service?

Comment: Use Alarm Manager instead